# Eclipse RAP Installation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rap

I a newbie with eclipse RAP, I see this how-to for installing Eclipse Rap http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRAP/article.html
but when i click on Launch a RAP Application I see this error

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /rap. Reason: 

    ProxyServlet: /rap

Powered by Jetty://
```

In Console I see this in red:

> 2012-04-17 10:27:14.890:INFO:org.mortbay.log:Logging to STDERRorg.mortbay.log via
>   org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
>   2012-04-17 10:27:15.134:INFO::jetty-6.1.x
>   2012-04-17 10:27:15.279:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:51074

I press F5 in browser but nothing, I change the port but nothing.
I don't know what the problem is.
I use win7 64 bit and use Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers:
Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857

I installed eclipse on Debian system and I see usual error now I undestand where is the problem?

can you help me?

Comment: Jetty has been started on a random port (51074), but there seems to be no entrypoint registered. I'd guess that some bundle is missing in your launch configuration. What is the URL you connect to? What is the output of `ss` in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the very same problem and found help in the following Eclipse Community Forum post:

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/987645/?srch=SelectChannelConnector#msg_987645

According to this, there is some trouble with the RAP version in the "Eclipse for RCP and RAP development" distribution. Instead I downloaded Eclipse classic and installed the RAP Tools 2.0 manually via "Help -> Install new software..." from http://download.eclipse.org/rt/rap/tools/2.0/. Having installed these tools and restarted Eclipse, the welcome page now has a RAP link I used to install and activate the RAP target platform.

After this trouble, my RAP projects worked. You might still get 404 errors, but now refreshing the page works. I hope this information helps you!

Answer (score 0):

[Bug 282756 - [Tooling] Browser is opened too early](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=282756)

From time to time the browser opened by the launcher is opened too early and the user is confronted with an error page.
This scares most first time users if you don't know that you just need to hit the refresh button.

=> The solution is to press the refresh button on the browser.